# How could we access the value in a dictionary that is present as a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

`marks={'A':[50,70,90],'B':[60,80,70],'C':[70,80,90]}`

In the above dictionary, I need to access the value of B and to find the average of list (i:e:(60+80+70)/3). How could I access the value and find the average? What I tried was...

```
marks={'A':[50,70,90],'B':[60,80,70],'C':[70,80,90]}
get_name=input()
for i in marks:
    if i==get_name:
        for j in i:
            add += marks[j]
print(add/3)
```

It shows up error. How to access the values in the dictionary of the list[60,80,70] with respect to key 'B'.

Comment: Use `marks.items()`. But probably `marks[get_name]` would be better.

Comment: `marks.get(get_name)` ?

Comment: `for j in marks[i]`. Also, you need to initialize the variable `add` to 0. Moreover, `j` IS the mark, so you need `add += j`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner -

```
avg = sum(marks['B'])/3
```

Comment: `len(marks['B'])`?

Comment: yeah probably better, although his example has always 3 numbers so hard to tell

Comment: So if it had n examples then the code can be `sum(marks['B'])/len(marks['B']) `

Answer (score 0):

`sum()` will total the value in that respective list and you just have to divide it by the size of the list.

```
input = 'A'
average = sum(marks[input])/len(marks[input])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
marks={'A':[50,70,90],'B':[60,80,70],'C':[70,80,90]}
```

For the above code, `marks[get_name]` should print out the list `[60,80,70]` through which the mean can be then taken.

To iterate over a dictionary you would use, `for key, val in marks.items()` and check if the provided user input `equals` to one of the `key` and then take the average.